# Is it possible to setup Firebase Analytics from an Express server?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, analytics

I have an Express-based application and I'd like to use Firebase Analytics to track events. It looks like [this isn't possible with node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#namespace). There is a *Firebase Admin SDK* for servers, but it doesn't look like analytics is supported based on its [feature matrix](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/).

Are Firebase server-side analytics called something else? Are they nested under another feature?

(It didn't look like it. But because I'm new to Firebase, I wanted to confirm before trying another approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase doesn't have any analytics products for backends.  Its focus is on Android, iOS, web, and Unity client apps and games.